# Is zero considered a positive integer in the Gamma function?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, probability-distributions

Within the Gamma distribution ${\Gamma(n,a)}$ there is the Gamma function which evaluated at n, ${\Gamma(n)}$, is defined as

$$
\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!
$$
for all positive integers. Is zero a positive integer within this context?

Comment: zero is never considered to be a 'positive' integer in any context.

Comment: But what about those that consider zero a natural number? Also, does this mean that ${\Gamma(0,a)}$ does not exist?

Comment: There is nothing natural about zero.

Comment: It does not matter whether you consider $0$ as a natural number or not. Definition of a positive number is pretty clear.

Comment: What about "Some authors begin the natural numbers with 0", from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Comment: Some authors are unnatural ;).

Comment: Haha, ok. Also thanks @JackYoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is only true for all integers $n\geq 1$. Notice that if it held for $n=0$, you would get a non-sensical statement like
$$\Gamma(0) = (-1)!,$$
and $(-1)!$ is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Forgot the difference between (-1)! and -1!..